# All SFML related maros empty despite CMake finding SFML

Tags: c++, cmake

As the title explains, any of the following SFML macros are empty despite CMake finding SFML:

1. SFML_INCLUDE_DIR
2. SFML_LIBRARIES
3. SFML_DEPENDENCIES

Being kinda new to CMake, I'm not actually sure what is going wrong here at all. Here's my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15 FATAL_ERROR)

project(Rain)
string(TOUPPER ${PROJECT_NAME} PROJECT_NAME_UPPER)

set(${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}_VERSION_MINOR 1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug" CACHE STRING "Set build type for the project")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror")

message("[${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}] CXX Standard: ${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}")
message("[${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}] Build type: ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
message("[${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}] CXX Flags: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(SRCS_CXX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
set(HDRS_CXX ${HDRS_CXX})
set(PROJ_LIB ${PROJ_LIB})
set(PROJ_DEP ${PROJ_DEP})

include(cmake/find_modules/find_modules.cmake)
message("PROJ_LIB: ${PROJ_LIB}")

if(SFML_FOUND)
    message("INCLUDE HEADERS: ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
else()
    message("[${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}] SFML NOT FOUND")
    if(WIN32)
        message("[${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}] Not implemented")
    elseif(APPLE)
        message("[${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}] Not implemented")
    elseif(UNIX)
        message("[${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}] Please type the following into your OS terminal to install Development SFML:")
        message("{${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}] sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev")
    else()
        message("[${PROJECT_NAME_UPPER}] Unknown OS. Please install SFML using your OS package manager.")
    endif(WIN32)
endif(SFML_FOUND)

# TODO: Create configuration header here when implemented.

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/dir_src.cmake)
include_directories(
    ${HDRS_CXX}
)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${HDRS_CXX}
    ${SRCS_CXX}
)

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${PROJ_LIB}
)
```

all my find_modules.cmake file has is:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/find_modules)

if(WIN32)
elseif(APPLE)
elseif(UNIX)
    set(SFML_ROOT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/SFML/unix" CACHE STRING "Path to SFML")
endif(WIN32)

find_package(SFML 2 COMPONENTS network audio graphics window system REQUIRED)
set(PROJ_LIB 
    ${PROJ_LIB}
    sfml-network
    sfml-audio
    sfml-graphics
    sfml-window
    sfml-system
)
```

It does however find the SFMLConfig.cmake file in the directory that I'm housing SFML in though...

I hope someone is able to help...

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the error I get:

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -g /home/jamie/Dev/Rain/src/RainMain.cpp -o /home/jamie/Dev/Rain/src/RainMain
/home/jamie/Dev/Rain/src/RainMain.cpp:2:10: fatal error: SFML/Window.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <SFML/Window.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

Comment: `find_package(SFML)` uses `FindSFML.cmake` script which you probably have in the `cmake/find_modules` directory. Read the beginning of that script, it usually explains which variables/targets it fills.

Comment: SFML 2.5 no longer uses that file anymore and neither am I (see the link below)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64667529/sfml-2-5-and-cmake

Comment: `find_package(SFML)` uses either `FindSFML.cmake` or `SFMLConfig.cmake` script. The latter script is not searched under `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. Please, show (add to the question post) output of CMake about SFML. It could contain a key which script is actually used.

Comment: As per the OP, it does find SFMLConfig.cmake where I have my SFML directory

Comment: So, read beginning of script `SFMLConfig.cmake` about usage of the script's results. E.g. according to [that script](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/cmake/SFMLConfig.cmake.in), it creates imported targets like `sfml-XXX`, so they could be used in `target_link_libraries` call like `target_link_libraries(myapp sfml-graphics sfml-audio)`.

Comment: OK, I get that bit, and I have done that but cmake is complaining that SFML/Window.hpp is not a file or directory...

Comment: Please, add your modified **code** (CMake) and the **exact error message** into the question post. Otherwise, it is difficult to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Added the modified code and the error to the OP

Comment: The command line `/usr/bin/g++ -g /home/jamie/Dev/Rain/src/RainMain.cpp -o /home/jamie/Dev/Rain/src/RainMain` doesn't look like the one generated by CMake: CMake usually separates **compiling** and **linking** steps. Also, this line misses for the linked libraries, which are specified in `target_link_libraries` call.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain but what could I do to fix this as I feel I'm close to being able to use SFML in my project but not quite